# Will there be data transfer fees using aws s3 cp (locally) to move data from my S3 bucket to my EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, aws-cli

The question is mostly self-explanatory.
If I run `aws s3 cp <s3_bucket> <ec2_host>` locally (assuming both the bucket and the instance are on the same region), does the data go from s3 to ec2 internally (in which case there are no data transfer costs), or does it go first from the bucket to my computer, and only then to the instance (in which case there are s3 download data transfer costs)?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Where are you running this command? The `aws s3 cp` command can only be used to copy to/from S3 and the machine on which the command is run.

Answer (score 1):

AWS [S3 pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/) writes:

> Transfers between S3 buckets or from Amazon S3 to any service(s) **within the same AWS Region** are **free**.

Please note that if you are using **NAT gateway** to access S3 from private subnet you will pay for NAT transfers. Use VPC S3 gateway endpoint instead.  So if you are using `aws s3 cp` from private subnet through NAT, you will pay for them.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html) for the `cp` command states this at the beginning:

```
  cp
<LocalPath> <S3Uri> or <S3Uri> <LocalPath> or <S3Uri> <S3Uri>
```

In other words, each of the `x` and `y` in `aws s3 cp <x> <y>` can be either a S3 URI or a local reference.  There is no option there to point it at an EC2 instance.  If you did try to run `aws s3 cp s3://bucketname/key.name 1.2.3.4`, you would just end up with a file called `1.2.3.4` on your machine.